# Scene2d progress bar not resizing

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I added a progress bar to my stage, and it gets a default width as expected. However, I do want to change the width a bit, but for some reason LibGDX don't. I've tried setSize, setWidth, setMinWidth at the background of the progress bar and changing the texture. Nothing works. The only thing I can get to change size of, is the knob.

Here's the code:

```
background = new Texture("progress_bar_texture");
knob = new Texture("knob_texture");

ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle pbs = new ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle();
pbs.background = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(background));       
pbs.knob = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(knob));
pbs.knobAfter = pbs.knob;

progressBar = new ProgressBar(0f, 80f, 1f, false, pbs);
progressBar.setWidth(400); // This doesn't change anything at all...

table.add(progressBar).right().colspan(1).expandX().padRight(40);
```

Comment: Setting the size of a widget in a table does not work because the table is managing its size. You must set the size of the cell that is returned when you add it to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Anton, you can increase the width of the ProgressBar within the table using 1. .colspan(2) or 2.Table.setWidth(). If you want precise (pixel-perfect) control of the position and size of the ProgressBar, add it to a Group instead of Table - then the things you tried ( setSize, setWidth, setMinWidth at the background of the progress bar) will work.